# Reading a power transformer ratings table

Tags: power, transformer

I'm  trying to read a rating table of a power transformer that is available for sale on Alibaba (link: https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Three-Phase-Step-Down-Distribution-Transformer_1600350385746.html?spm=a2700.7724857.normal_offer.d_title.4d2a5f484VjJCX). I just want to know that there are multiple voltage ratings on it i.e. 110v/220v/400v/3kv. There are four voltages mentioned in this ratio. All I want to know is what this represents and how it gives the information about the voltage ratio of transformer.

Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't. The way a lot of Alibaba listings work is, they offer a range of products, you actually talk to someone (online) and negotiate the specific one you want from that list of voltages.

Answer (score 1):

Down the page of the linked information, a table shows: 10kva; 110v/220v/400v/3kv; Dyn11/Yd11/Yyno. That seems to be a 10kva transformer that has 3 low voltage options for 3kv high voltage with three vector group connections. However, the overview indicates this is an autotransformer. It seems to me that there is not a way to achieve that with an autotransformer.